# Any Reason Why I Can't Run a Windows Service as a Domain User?

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory, windows-service

Any reason why I can't add a domain user as the logged on role for a Windows service? The syntax of the domain name and user is correct and the password is definitely correct, but whenever I try to set the logged on user as a domain user, I get an error saying the user name or password is incorrect. Any ideas? I'm trying to run the cruise control.net service as a domain user. Also, the cruise control.net service is running on a machine that is on the same domain.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may need to grant the user account the right to [log on as a service](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc739424%28WS.10%29.aspx)